# (Vue) Impact on performance of local scope variables in computed properties

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

Does defining variables inside of a computed property have any impact on the perfomance of Vue components?

*Background*: I built a table component which generates a HTML table generically from the passed data and has different filters per column, filter for the whole table, sort keys, etc., so I'm defining a lot of local variables inside the computed property.

Imagine having an array of objects:

```js
let data = [
  { id: "y", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { id: "z", a: 11, b: 22, c: 33 }
]
```

..which is used by a Vue component to display the data:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="filterKey" />
  </div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in filteredData" :key="item.id">
        <td v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">
          {{ value }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

The data gets filtered via input:

```vue
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    passedData: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      filterKey: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      // defining local scope variables
      let data = this.passedData;
      let filterKey = this.filterKey;

      data = data.filter((e) => {
        // filter by filterKey or this.filterKey
      });

      return data;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My question refers to `let data = ..` and `let filterKey = ..` as `filteredData()` gets triggered from any change of the `filterKey` (defined in `data()`) so the local variable gets updated too, although they're not "reactive" in a Vue way.

Is there any impact on the performance when defining local variables inside a computed property? Should you use the reactive variables from `data()` (e. g. `this.filterKey`) directly inside of the computed property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to test if something affects performance, is to actually test it.

According to my tests below, it is consistency more than 1000% slower to use `this.passedData` instead of adding a variable on top of the function. (869ms vs 29ms)

Make sure you run your benchmarks on the target browsers you write your application for the best results.

```js
function time(name, cb) {
  var t0 = performance.now();
  const res = cb();
  if(res !== 20000000) {
    throw new Error('wrong result: ' + res);
  }
  var t1 = performance.now();
  document.write("Call to "+name+" took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.<br>")
}
function withoutLocalVar() {
  const vue = new Vue({
    computed: {
      hi() {
        return 1;
      },
      hi2() {
        return 1;
      },
      test() {
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { // 10 000 000
          sum += this.hi + this.hi2;
        }
        return sum;
      },
    }
  })
  return vue.test;
}
function withLocalVar() {
  const vue = new Vue({
    computed: {
      hi() {
        return 1;
      },
      hi2() {
        return 1;
      },
      test() {
        let sum = 0;
        const hi = this.hi;
        const hi2 = this.hi2;
        for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { // 10 000 000
          sum += hi + hi2;
        }
        return sum;
      },
    }
  })
  return vue.test;
}
function benchmark() {
  const vue = new Vue({
    computed: {
      hi() {
        return 1;
      },
      hi2() {
        return 1;
      },
      test() {
        let sum = 0;
        const hi = 1;
        const hi2 = 1;
        for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { // 10 000 000
          sum += hi + hi2;
        }
        return sum;
      },
    }
  })
  return vue.test;
}
time('withoutLocalVar - init', withoutLocalVar);
time('withLocalVar - init', withLocalVar);
time('benchmark - init', benchmark);
time('withoutLocalVar - run1', withoutLocalVar);
time('withLocalVar - run1', withLocalVar);
time('benchmark - run1', benchmark);
time('withoutLocalVar - run2', withoutLocalVar);
time('withLocalVar - run2', withLocalVar);
time('benchmark - run2', benchmark);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I'm actually interested in the technical background of this behavior: Vue's computed properties are cached based on their dependencies, but this has nothing to do with the local variables at first glance.

Comment: One technical detail that might cause the speedup is that the javascript engine can be 100% sure the value is never going to change, and can then turn on optimizations that it is otherwise unable to turn on. That's the reason why it's important to benchmark it in your own app, as that might go in a differend route in the javascript optimizer (in my case, the optimizer may already do 1 + 1 = 2 and then use that one to make the sum calculation quicker)

Comment: I recreated your example with strings instead of integers and executing a  filter function instead of summing up the numbers - the result is the same. I will eventually post this at the Vue forum to get some further technical insight.

Comment: Actually: Using the loops is counterintuitive, as the loop calls Vue's reactivity getter again and again. You would call the getter only once in a real-world example, so the huge performance differences in this example are not meaningful (as long as you're not using a loop in your computed property, of course).